# Running script in selected path

Tags: vb.net, process, cmd, directory

I currently have this piece of code:

```
   Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)



            If dlgFolder.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

                txtPath.Text = dlgFolder.SelectedPath


                Try

                    Dim CopyFile As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, "pdftk.exe")
                    Dim CopyLocation As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdftk.exe")
                    Dim pyScript As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, "pdfmerge.py")
                    Dim pyLocation As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")

                    System.IO.File.Copy(CopyFile, CopyLocation, True)
                    System.IO.File.Copy(pyScript, pyLocation, True)

                Catch copyError As IOException
                Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message)
                End Try         
            End If
End Sub
```

This copies two files in the current working directory (which will be the default install folder) to the selected path from the Fodler Dialog Browser. This works correctly.

Now what I want to do is too run "pdfmerge.py" into the selected folder path. I tried the below code but the script is still running in the current working directory.

```
Sub BtnNowClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim myProcess As Process
        Dim processFile As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")

        myProcess.Start(processFile, dlgFolder.SelectedPath)



    End Sub
```

Comment: If you `Debug.Print dlgFolder.SelectedPath` in `BtnNowClick` what do you get?  Also, are you sure the `Try` block is completing in `Button1Click`?

Comment: @jonsca Yeah the try Block is working good. The problem is the command line argument.. I want to run pdfmerge.py from dlgFolder.SelectedPath not the current working directory

Comment: I see what you are saying now, the process start, despite having the complete path of the file is invoking it locally.  Hmmm... There must be a way around that with permissions, but I could see how the system was set up that way.  Apologies that I misunderstood before.

Comment: I think that's what you need, look on the MSDN page to refine what arguments are required (but older sources from 03-04 say that all you need to do is pass the working directory in as the 3rd argument, see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/start_an_external_app.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the overload of [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx) that takes 5 arguments.

```
Start ( _
fileName As String, _
arguments As String, _
userName As String, _
password As SecureString, _
domain As String _
)
```

You may be able to pass in `null` for `userName` and `password`, but if your directory is outside of the standard ones that you have permission for, you may need to put your username and password in.  `domain` would be the working directory, I think.

Comment: I did not quite understand this. The username, password and domain should be invented? And once you create the function, how do I use it to call "pdfmerge.py" in the dlgFolder.selectedPath?

Comment: That's just the signature for the `Process.Start` function from MSDN.  Since you'd be starting a process in a directory outside of Documents, etc., places your account would normally have access to, I think you need the username+password (what you log into windows with) as credentials.  From the description of `Start` I thought that `domain` was the directory the process starts in.  However, I think Hand-E-Food may be on to something in that regard.  You would pass the arguments you were passing into Start same as you did before.

Comment: So, I think it would be `Process.Start(processFile,"pdfmerge.py","YourUsername","your Windows password",dlgFolder.selectedPath)`

Comment: So basically that would make the program only usable by one user? Isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know how you would handle that.  Try making a toy program to test and see if, in fact, those are all the correct parameters.

Comment: @Brian But really give the other answer a try because I think he's onto something.  I'm afraid you're going to run into UAC (user access control) hangups, but test it and see.

Comment: something just came to mind. is it possible to change the current working directory using Directory.SetCurrentDirectory and run "pdfmerge.py" from there? Or would it still run the script from the original directory?

Comment: Yes. It sets the directory to the selected path and runs the script from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the process's working directory.

```
Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
p.FileName = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")
p.WorkingDirectory = dlgFolder.SelectedPath
Process.Start(p)
```

One question: are you ensuring the `dlgFolder.SelectedPath` is correct?  Without knowing the inner workings of your program, it appears possible to press `BtnNow` before `Button1`, meaning `dlgFolder.SelectedPath` won't have been set by the user.

Comment: I did `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dlgFolder.SelectedPath)` and that seemed to solve the problem.